# Get the children of an element in puppeteer

Tags: jquery, node.js, puppeteer

So my goal here is to count the number of children of a div class that has inside it multiple div's; I do that by selecting the div then using the `children` attribute, and then I count the children with their `length` property and  print it.

To achieve my goal i'm trying to implement this code in puppeteer:

```js
$('div[data-test-selector="center-window__content"]').children
```

(which works flawlessly on the chrome debug console)

this is my converted code:

```js
let childrens = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div[data-test-selector="center-window__content"]'), i => Array.from(i.children));
```

However this expression evaluates to `undefined`.

On their documentation for `evaluate` it is said that:

> if the function passed to the page.evaluate returns a non-Serializable value, then page.evaluate resolves to undefined.

Is that the case here? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

So in the end I think that puppeteer couldn't serialize the children array for some reason.

I ended up using that:

```js
const notifs = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return (Array.from(document.querySelector('[data-test-selector="center-window__content"]').children).length);
})
```

Thanks to @TerryLennox for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might give this a try:

```
const children = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return (Array.from(document.querySelector('div[data-test-selector="center-window__content"]').children).length);
})
console.log("Result:", children);
```

Testing against this

**html**

```
<html>
<div data-test-selector="center-window__content">
    some text
    <div>Child 1</div>
    <div>Child 2</div>
    <div>Child 3</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however this returns `undefined` again.

Comment: Hmmm, weird. I see an array of the div children.. I wonder what the difference is.. I'll post the html I'm using!

Comment: So this code: `const children = await page.evaluate(() => { return (Array.from(document.querySelector('div[data-test-selector="centerwindow__content"]').children).length);})` worked for me.

Comment: So in the end I think that puppeteer couldn't serialize the children array for some reason. I added an edit to your post with what worked for me :D